# Interpolate time series and resample/pivot. How to get the expected output

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
Video | Start              | End                | Duration |  
vid1  |2018-10-02 16:00:29 |2018-10-02 20:07:05 |   246    |  
vid2  |2018-10-04 16:03:08 |2018-10-04 16:10:11 |     7    |  
vid3  |2018-10-04 10:13:40 |2018-10-06 12:07:38 |   113    |
```

What I want to do is resample dataframe by 10 minutes by start column and assign 1 if the video lasted in that timestamp and 0 if not.
The desired output is:

```
Start              | vid1 | vid2 | vid3 |
2018-10-02 16:00:00|  1   |  0   | 0    |  
2018-10-02 16:10:00|  1   |  0   | 0    |
... 
2018-10-04 16:10:00|  0   |  1   | 0    |  
2018-10-04 16:20:00|  0   |  0   | 1    |
```

The output is presented only for visualization the output, hence, it can contain errors.
The problem is that I can not resample dataframe in a way to make a desired crosstab output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Video'], 
                             index=pd.date_range(x['Start'].floor('10T'), 
                                                 x['End'].ceil('10T'), 
                                                 freq='10T')), axis=1)\
  .stack().str.get_dummies().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
                     vid1   vid2   vid3 
2018-10-02 16:00:00      1      0      0
2018-10-02 16:10:00      1      0      0
2018-10-02 16:20:00      1      0      0
2018-10-02 16:30:00      1      0      0
2018-10-02 16:40:00      1      0      0
...                    ...    ...    ...
2018-10-06 11:30:00      0      0      1
2018-10-06 11:40:00      0      0      1
2018-10-06 11:50:00      0      0      1
2018-10-06 12:00:00      0      0      1
2018-10-06 12:10:00      0      0      1

[330 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: customized a little, but work like a charm! thanks!